# Permutation Adjacency matrix

Tags: graph-theory

What is the name of a directed graph with a permutation matrix as its  adjacency matrix?
I mean if (N,E) is a graph and its adjacency matrix is a permutation matrix
what is the suitable name for this graph?

Answer (score 2):

Write the permutation as a product of disjoint cycles. Assume there are $k$ cycles of lengths $\ell_1,\ell_2,\ldots, \ell_k$. Then this graph is  is a disjoint union of  circuits  having these numbers as lengths. (if $k=1$, that is the permutation is a cycle, then it is a single circuit and hence connected). If any of the $\ell_i=1$ then that corresponds to an isolated vertex.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is your suggestion to call this graph?

Comment: Is "permutation graph" suitable?

Comment: There must be standard terminology by graph theorists; so I would not attempt to coin a word.